# How to reference a different domain model from within a map with spring boot correctly?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I've the following mongodb document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a068b13a4b500d7f2c72a2"), 
    "results" : [
        {
            "position" : NumberInt(12), 
            "product" : DBRef("product", ObjectId("579f92cfcb22890ba7b0ae15"))
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i map this document correctly to a spring boot domain/model class using spring-data-mongodb?

Using the following attribute in the model works but i think it's not clear enough because i've to ensure that the object in the map is an objectId or DBRef.

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> results;
```

Also creating a separate result model and using `private List<Result> results;` didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something roughly equivalent to this should do the trick:

```
class MyDocument {
  ObjectID id;
  List<Result> results;
  …
}

class Result {
  int position;
  @DBRef Product product;
  …
}

class Product {
  ObjectId id;
}
```

The important bits:

- A dedicated type for the objects embedded in the base document.
- A pointer to the referred-to document using `@DBRef`
- The referred-to object having to use `ObjectId` as identifier type

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working like you described, also without the usage of ObjectIds in the referred-to object. I'm using String id in my spring models and it's working fine.